# Unable to switch to root user after ssh into the instance using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh, sudo

I have a scenario to automate the manual build update process via shell script on multiple VM nodes.
For the same, I am trying the below sample script to first ssh into the instance and then switch to root user to perform the further steps like copying the build to archives directory under /var and then proceed with the later steps.
Below is the sample script,

```
#!/bin/sh
publicKey='/path/to/publickey'
buildVersion='deb9.deb build'
buildPathToStore='/var/cache/apt/archives/'
pathToHomedir='/home'

script="whoami && pwd && ls -la && whoami && mv ${buildVersion} ${buildPathToStore} && find ${buildPathToStore} | grep deb9"

for var in "$@" 
do 
  copyBuildPath="${publicKey} ${buildVersion} ${var}:/home/admin/"
  echo "copy build ==>" ${copyBuildPath}
  scp -r -i ${copyBuildPath}
  ssh -i $publicKey -t $var "sudo su - & ${script}; " # This shall execute all commands as root
done
```

So the CLI stats for the above script are something like this

```
admin //this is the user check
/home/admin
total 48
drwxr-xr-x 6 admin admin 4096 Dec  6 00:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root  root  4096 Nov 17 14:07 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 admin admin 4096 Nov 17 14:00 .ansible
drwx------ 2 admin admin 4096 Nov 23 18:26 .appdata
-rw------- 1 admin admin 5002 Dec  6 17:47 .bash_history
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin  220 May 16  2017 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin 3506 Jun 14  2019 .bashrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin  675 May 16  2017 .profile
drwx------ 4 admin admin 4096 Nov 23 18:26 .registry
drwx------ 2 admin admin 4096 Jun 21  2019 .ssh
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin    0 Dec  6 19:42 testFile.txt
-rw------- 1 admin admin 2236 Jun 21  2019 .viminfo
admin
```

If I  use sudo su -c  and remove &
like:

```
ssh -i $publicKey -t $var "sudo su -c ${script}; "
```

Then for once **whoami** returns the user as root but the working directory still prints as **/home/admin** instead of **/root**
And the next set of commands are still accounted for admin user rather than the root. So the admin user do not have the privileges to move the build to archive directory and install the build.

Using & I want to ensure that the further steps are being done in the background.
Not sure how to proceed ahead with this. Good suggestions are most welcome right now :)

Comment: I never understood `sudo su`. Why not `sudo bash -c` or just only `su -c`? `sudo su` is like `sudo sudo`.

Comment: Hi @KamilCuk I tried your suggestion, but it did't help my usecase, On executing sudo bash -c, it still behaves in the same manner as I explained in the post. Also, sudo -i takes me to the root  shell, do you think i need to set some ids before passing the command script using -c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> "sudo su - & ${script}; "
> ```

expands to:

```
sudo su - & whoami && pwd && ...
```

First `sudo su -` is run *in the background*. Then the command chain is executed.

> ```
>  sudo su -c ${script};
> ```

expands to:

```
 sudo su -c whoami && pwd && ...
```

So first `sudo su - whoami` is executed, which runs `whoami` as root. Then if this command is successful, then `pwd` is executed. As normal user.

It is utterly hard to correctly pass commands to execute on remote site using ssh. It is increasingly hard to do it with `sudo su` - the command will be *triple* (or twice?) word splitted - one time by ssh, then by the shell, then by the shell run by `sudo su`.

If you do not need interactive communication, it's best to use a here document with `-s` shell option, something along (untested):

```
# DO NOT store commands to use in a variable.
# or if you do and you know what you are doing, properly quote it (printf "%q ") and run it via eval
script() { 
      set -euo pipefail
      whoami
      pwd
      ls -la
      whoami
      mv "$buildVersion" "$buildPathToStore"
      find "$buildPathToStore" | grep deb9
}

ssh ... "sudo bash -s" <<EOF
echo "Yay! anything here!"
echo "Note that here document delimiter is not quoted!"
$(
     # safely import context to work with
     # note how command substitution is executed on host side
     declare -f script
     # pass variables too!
     declare -p buildVersion buildPathToStore buildPathToStore 
)
script

EOF
```

Comment: it is also possible to store script in file and use ssh ... "sudo bash -s" <<(cat file.sh)

Comment: Sure. `< <(cat file.sh)` is a useless use of `cat` and `<( ...)` (and there's a space between `< <(...)`). It's just `<file.sh`.

Comment: yes, there is a space, but oh thanks, I can improve my code :)

Comment: @KamilCuk: the suggestion did work smoothly. Many thanks to you +1, One doubt around declare -f steps just before calling script, do we need to explicitly declare function and variables before script? It shall fetch them from the current scope already, ain't it?

Comment: There is no "current scope". `ssh` is executing a separate program on a different computer with completely different environment and "scope". What ever you want to have there, you need to send.

Comment: Okay, That makes sense. I see even if I try passing -t before invoking ssh on an instance, it complains of not able to act as stdin, "Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.". So yeah, it will need all inputs that the main script requires to function.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `su` alone it keeps you in your actual directory, if you use `su -` it simulates the root login.
You should write : `su - root -c ${script};`